# HAProxy for Jira can't show static files

Tags: haproxy, jira

When using haproxy set load balancer for Jira, made config file /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg as:

```
frontend jira
    bind :::8080 v4v6
    # acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
    # acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js

    # use_backend static          if url_static
    default_backend             jira

backend jira
    balance     roundrobin

    server jira1 [IP1]:8080 check
    server jira2 [IP2]:8080 check
```

This server with IP as 192.168.0.1. When access this IP got non-static page seems like didn't load CSS correctly.

But if access `IP1` or `IP2` directly, I can get the URL correctly.

Is there something about configuration I missed for HAProxy?

Comment: what have you looked at so far?

Comment: @Sohan What do you mean `looked at`?

Comment: have you searched if there are similar issues around net?

Comment: @Sohan Yes, didn't find any good results.

Comment: see if this help https://www.gilesorr.com/blog/haproxy-static-content.html